# Função retornando None, quando o if ou else é executado

Tags: python

Como faço para a seguinte função não retornar `None`?

```
def dif(x, z):
    if x != z:
        print('\nNúmeros diferentes')
        return
    else:
        print('\nNúmeros iguais')
        return


n1 = int(input('Um número: '))
n2 = int(input('Outro número: '))

print(dif(n1, n2))
```

Answer (score 4):

Do jeito que a função foi escrita, ela não retorna nenhum valor, por isso o *none*. Para que ela retorne a *string* que você quer mostrar, faça:

```
def dif(x, z):
    if x != z:
        return '\nNúmeros diferentes';
    else:
        return '\nNúmeros iguais';


n1 = int(input('Um número: '))
n2 = int(input('Outro número: '))

print(dif(n1, n2))
```

Ou então, faça uma função *void*, que não retorna nenhum valor, e que apenas mostre a *string* na tela, e chame a função de outra forma:

```
def dif(x, z):
    if x != z:
        print('\nNúmeros diferentes')
    else:
        print('\nNúmeros iguais')


n1 = int(input('Um número: '))
n2 = int(input('Outro número: '))

dif(n1, n2)
```

[Veja funcionando no repl.it](https://repl.it/@Jvsierra_/UsedChiefArchive#main.py)

Comment: Antes de chegar no primeiro ponto final mandei o voto de utilidade.